# Function ExecCmd, used to work in access 2007 but no more in access 2013 (64bit)

Tags: shell, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I used to be able to run command lines running external programs (like exiftool or image magick) with the function below in my access 2007 db.
I migrated to access 2013 and after a few code adaptations, the DB works, except this function ExecCmd. When I use it I get no error but nothing happens.

Can anyone help ? Either by showing me whats wrong or suggesting a better way to do the same.

```
Public Const SEE_MASK_DOENVSUBST As Long = &H200
Public Const SEE_MASK_IDLIST As Long = &H4
Public Const SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS As Long = &H40
Public Const SW_HIDE As Long = 0
Public Const SW_SHOW As Long = 5
Public Const WAIT_TIMEOUT As Long = 258&

Public Type SHELLEXECUTEINFOA
    cbSize As Long
    fMask As Long
    hwnd As Long
    lpVerb As String
    lpFile As String
    lpParameters As String
    lpDirectory As String
    nShow As Long
    hInstApp As Long
    lpIDList As Long
    lpClass As String
    hkeyClass As Long
    dwHotKey As Long
    hIcon As Long
    hProcess As Long
End Type
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByRef lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecuteEx Lib "shell32.dll" (ByRef lpExecInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFOA) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long



Public Function ExecCmd(ByVal vsCmdLine As String, Optional ByRef vsParameters As String, Optional ByRef vsCurrentDirectory As String = vbNullString, Optional ByVal vnShowCmd As Long = SW_SHOW, Optional ByVal vnTimeOut As Long = 200) As Long
    Dim lpShellExInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFOA
        With lpShellExInfo
            .cbSize = Len(lpShellExInfo)
            .lpDirectory = vsCurrentDirectory
            .lpVerb = "open"
            .lpFile = vsCmdLine
            .lpParameters = vsParameters
            .nShow = vnShowCmd
            .fMask = SEE_MASK_DOENVSUBST Or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS Or SEE_MASK_IDLIST
        End With

        If ShellExecuteEx(lpShellExInfo) Then
            Do While WaitForSingleObject(lpShellExInfo.hProcess, vnTimeOut) = WAIT_TIMEOUT
                DoEvents
            Loop

            GetExitCodeProcess lpShellExInfo.hProcess, ExecCmd
            CloseHandle lpShellExInfo.hProcess
        Else
            ExecCmd = vbError
        End If
    End Function
```

I found another similar function, but the first one was better, if only because It had the ability to run the command hidden.
This works:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type STARTUPINFO
 cb As Long
 lpReserved As String
 lpDesktop As String
 lpTitle As String
 dwX As Long
 dwY As Long
 dwXSize As Long
 dwYSize As Long
 dwXCountChars As Long
 dwYCountChars As Long
 dwFillAttribute As Long
 dwFlags As Long
 wShowWindow As Integer
 cbReserved2 As Integer
 lpReserved2 As Long
 hStdInput As Long
 hStdOutput As Long
 hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
 hProcess As Long
 hThread As Long
 dwProcessID As Long
 dwThreadID As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
 hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
 lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
 lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
 ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
 ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
 lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
 PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
 hObject As Long) As Long

Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const INFINITE = -1&

Public Sub ExecCmd(cmdline As String)
 Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
 Dim start As STARTUPINFO
 Dim ReturnValue As Integer

 ' Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure:
 start.cb = Len(start)

 ' Start the shelled application:
 ReturnValue = CreateProcessA(0&, cmdline$, 0&, 0&, 1&, _
 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc)

 ' Wait for the shelled application to finish:
 Do
 ReturnValue = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, 0)
 DoEvents
 Loop Until ReturnValue <> 258

 ReturnValue = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recreate your issue using a simple test case. The VBA procedure...

```vbs
Sub test()
    Dim r As Variant
    r = ExecCmd("cscript.exe", "C:\Users\Public\Documents\foo.vbs", "", 0)
End Sub
```

...worked fine under 32-bit Access 2013 but failed silently under 64-bit Access 2013. However, the following code does seem to work under 64-bit Access 2013:

```vbs
Sub test2()
    Dim sh As Object  ' WshShell
    Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sh.Run "cscript.exe C:\Users\Public\Documents\foo.vbs", 0
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

For more information, see

[Run Method (Windows Script Host)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: API calls in 64bit are different.
Code below works: appli is launched and the code waits for it to finish before going further.
Best of all: a parameter controls the visibility of the app window: very useful to run a background batch of command line processes without poisoning the display or the focus.

Thanks for the help !

```vbs
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW& = &H1
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const INFINITE = -1&

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Long
    hStdInput As Long
    hStdOutput As Long
    hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As Long
    hThread As Long
    dwProcessID As Long
    dwThreadID As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
    lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
    lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
    PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hObject As Long) As Long

Public Sub ShellWait(Pathname As String, Optional WindowStyle As Long)
    Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim start As STARTUPINFO
    Dim ret As Long
    ' Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure:
    With start
        .cb = Len(start)
        If Not IsMissing(WindowStyle) Then
            .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            .wShowWindow = WindowStyle
        End If
    End With
    ' Start the shelled application:
    ret& = CreateProcessA(0&, Pathname, 0&, 0&, 1&, _
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc)
    ' Wait for the shelled application to finish:
    ret& = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE)
    ret& = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
End Sub
```